# How can i resolve dns with TIdDNSResolver?

Tags: delphi, indy

when try to resolve dns i am getting query refused by dns error error . am i wrong with that code can you please check ?

```
function Lookup(const Name: String): String;
var
  X: Integer;
  DNS: TIdDNSResolver;
begin
  DNS:= TIdDNSResolver.Create(nil);
  try
    DNS.Host := 'mail.relativ.art';
    DNS.WaitingTime := 5000;
    DNS.QueryType:= [qtMX];
    try DNS.Resolve(Name); except on E: Exception do begin writeln(E.Message); end; end;
    for X:= 0 to DNS.QueryResult.Count-1 do begin
      if DNS.QueryResult[X].RecType = qtMX then
        Result:= TMXRecord(DNS.QueryResult[X]).ExchangeServer;
    end;
  finally
    DNS.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

A hostname with `mail` in its name, like `mail.relativ.art`, is likely not a DNS server.

You need to set the `Host` property to an actual DNS server (preferrably one provided by your ISP, or a public one like Google), and then pass the desired target name to `Resolve()`.

If you are trying to query MX records for `mail.relativ.art`, then that is the target host to resolve, not the DNS server to send the query to, eg:

```
DNS:= TIdDNSResolver.Create(nil);
try
  DNS.Host := '8.8.8.8'; // Google public DNS
  DNS.WaitingTime := 5000;
  DNS.QueryType := [qtMX];
  try
    DNS.Resolve('mail.relativ.art');
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      WriteLn(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
  for X:= 0 to DNS.QueryResult.Count-1 do
  begin
    if DNS.QueryResult[X].RecType = qtMX then
      Result := TMXRecord(DNS.QueryResult[X]).ExchangeServer;
  end;
finally
  DNS.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. so @Remy how to smtpserver send redirect email to target host? i wrote smtprelay dnsserver with local dns to client says succesfuly send but gmail did not receive email. thanks

Comment: @relativ that is a completely new question that should be posted separate from this question. Also, Indy has an smtp relay component, have you looked at it yet?

Comment: just telling me when relay send mail to gmail , gmail understood like direct relay, but all email servers blocked relay messaging. How gmail get from smtp server .

Comment: @relativ again, that question is not related to THIS question regarding DNS. Please post a separate question about your Gmail issues.